# Physics books with practical applications

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, applied-physics

It is very important when learning a physical subject to know how it applies to nature, so that when one is out on a walk one can see how the abstract physical principles appear in nature. I believe this is very important for imprinting the concept in the student's mind.

To that end, what are some good (undergraduate level) physics text-books that contain many practical illustrations? There is no need for these to be of the "lab experiment" kind; they can simply be illustrations that show how something applies in nature.

Comment: I don't think you need any special textbooks for that purpose. By the time you have successfully finished a four year physics degree, you won't have any trouble mapping observations directly to sub-fields (like optics or atomic physics) and individual effects. Physics without experiments is not possible, though. If you don't know the relevant experiments/observations, then you don't know science. If you are interested in material sciences or magnet design or technical optics, then you will have to focus on the details of those "crafts" which all come with a small library of special literature.

Comment: Don't know for other topics, but if you want to do some amazing home-experiments on waves without any need of some high lab apparatuses, then get this book: [Berkeley Physics Course: Vol III: Waves: Frank S Crawford Jr.](http://www.amazon.com/Waves-Berkeley-Physics-Course-Vol/dp/0070048606).